# Expressing the diagonal of a matrix filtered by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am trying to extract the mathematical expression of creating a set of elements from the diagonal of a matrix, but after filtering by a vector.
For example:

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, $\mathbf{v}$ a $3 \times 1$ vector, and $\mathbf{R}$ be the resulting $3 \times 1$ vector:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Which would be the expression of this operation? I am looking for a notation expressed in a way that specifies the relationship between $\mathbf{R}$ and $A$ and $\mathbf{v}$. I have thought something like:

$\mathbf{D} = \{  A_{ii} \mid i \in [0, N] \}$

$\mathbf{R} = \{D_{i} \land \mathbf{v}_{i} \mid i \in [0, N] \}$

Would that be correct?

Comment: $D$ is a set and $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector. So, what do you mean by $D_i \land \mathbf{v}_{i}$?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that. I meant to express an AND operation between the two elements.

Comment: Does that mean you only work in binary?

Comment: Yes, both A, v and R are supposed to contain binary elements.

Comment: in that case, as long as you carefully define $D_i$ and $\mathbf{v}_i$, you definition of $\mathbf{R}$ should be: $ \mathbf{R}_i=D_i \land \mathbf{v}_i$. Rather than the set builder you made for $\mathbf{R}$ you made in the post.

Comment: I'm not personally aware of a more rigorous way to describe what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Let `diag()` return the main diagonal of its matrix argument as a column vector, and `Diag()` construct a diagonal matrix from its vector argument.

Also note that the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ between two vectors is equivalent to making one of them a diagonal matrix and multiplying it by the other.

Therefore the filtering operation is
$$\eqalign{
R \;=\; v\odot{\rm diag}(A) \;=\; {\rm Diag}(v)\cdot{\rm diag}(A)
}$$
Note that all elements of $v\,$ and ${\rm diag}(A)$ are either $\,0$ or ${\tt1}.\,$ Thus a logical AND operation between elements is equivalent to integer multiplication, so a standard Hadamard product is sufficient to describe the filtering operation.